# Tracking online users with a stateless architecture

Tags: database, web-applications, rest, api, authentication

I own a stateless architecture, exchanging a JWT token between client and server at authentication time.

I want to store in database (once per day) a timestamp related to the user access.
Indeed, I would like to be able to show who was accessing the app, with a margin of 1 day (kind of rather online users).

A good solution (**to avoid hitting database at each client request**) I guessed would be to add a property to the JWT token called `recentUserAccessTimestamp` and to send it to the client at every request.

Question is: Is it a good practice to make the client replace its existing token (in LocalStorage for instance in case of WebApp) right after each request on my server?

Comment: Would this not then make it stateful?

Comment: Stateless in a sense that there is nothing stored in memory (no Memcache, no Redis etc..).

Comment: That is different than what most people would consider a stateless service.  Stateless typically implies that no state information is passed between client and server.  If the server wants to cache things, then that would be opaque to the client.

Comment: I think the exact contrary : stateless promotes exchanging information between client and server without storing anything on the server. What I want to store in database is not a direct result of one of those exchanges. The server does not store information of connection or anything else relative to a particular client instance.

Comment: I think we may have the same view, just worded differently.  In either case, I think it would be worth while to simply store this information server side in the database in some sort of logging / audit table.  Just because your application may be saving this information doesn't mean the exposed service has to behave differently because of it.

Comment: What is different from my OP ? I stated I want to store this data in an audit table while ensuring a very low hit on the DB

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question, why should the client be transmitted `recentUserAccessTimestamp`?  To me it seems like you're just transferring that state information to the client.  If the client sends the old token again, is the system going to behave differently than if it were to send the newer token?

Comment: The solution I guessed would be : 1) The client logs in. 2) The server generated a JWT token also containing the current timestamp ( date of now) 3) The client stores this token in localStorage so that it sends it to each further request. 4) Few times later, client makes a request sending  the passed timestamp contained in the previously stored token. 5) The server, before treating the request, checks weither one day has elapsed between the previous query. 6) if elapsed, server updates database ("recentUserTimestamp") generates a new jwt token with the a refreshed timestamp of now and so on.

Comment: So the main drawback of this solution I can figure out is that the client has to store the jwt token after EACH request, to be able to send the potentially provided recent timestamp.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to put this in the JWT?  Why not use a cookie?

Comment: @ErikEidt Actually, my client is a mobile app ( ios/android) and a mobile app can't handle any cookies. The only way to store data on this kind of client is with the help of browser's localstorage.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. You should assume you don't really control the client that much, and certainly I wouldn't trust the client itself to send you a time stamp for the last time it did something on your server. The server should know that. Is there any reason you don't want to update the DB on each user request. Doing this is common practice, and you probably already save a lot of user data in server logs for each interaction with the client. A simple DB update for each interaction should not add much overhead, if it does you have bigger problems.

Comment: @CormacMulhall the reason is that my db is not on the same network. I want to avoid any network latency as possible.

Comment: @Mik378 In that case you could do an async call to the database so that it doesn't block the response to the client. The client doesn't need to care if the last accessed value is actually saved in the database so you don't need to block the response to the client waiting for confirmation that the value was saved. There are various ways to do this, worker queues, worker threads, non-blocking requests etc.

Comment: @CormacMulhall You won't block the client with your solution, but you will block a thread on your server ;)  since my database doesn't have a non-blocking driver.

Comment: Shouldn't really matter though, your operating system should take care of task switching between the threads. If you don't like threads you can use a worker model that uses processes rather than threads (with a worker queue to manage jobs, see Celery in Python or SideKiq in Ruby) 

The operation of sending a request to a database and waiting for a response is an IO bound request rather than CPU bound (ie the thread/process can sleep while waiting for the database response, freeing the CPU). Even on a single core CPU machine this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly rotate the JWT across requests, but you'll quickly run into a couple problems:

- What side-channel do you use to issue the JWT? A HTTP response header? An augmented response body?
- How can a client issue more than one concurrent request? The JWT is rotated across request/response cycles, so reusing an existing JWT will result in funky race conditions.

You said that you don't want to update the DB on every client request. But if you rotate the JWT, would you not have to store the new JWT in Redis or another persistence mechanism anyway? Therefore I think that you should simply store the user access data upon each request.

Marketing folks go bananas for the kind of analytics data you'll be capturing. By storing it *en masse*, you might just save a coworker a lot of pain down the line, and it will make you look like a hero.

One final thought. If you can tolerate some loss of the data in question, just write it to an in-memory queue in your main application. A background thread can periodically flush the data to a persistence store. Now everyone wins.

Comment: this part is wrong : "would you not have to store the new JWT in Redis" =>  JWT token is only stored on client ( localstorage in my case) , never on server, that s the whole benefit of JWT.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this a few minutes earlier and I stumbled upon this question. It's weird, I was expecting to get straight to the point answers to this.

So I came up with mine. I believe the best way to do it is to handle it through a 3rd party or even a second server of yours. i.e.: if you're building a mobile app, you could integrate an analytics tool that allows you to set sessions both on successful logins and logouts.

If you don't have control over the clients and want to do it server side:

- Set the expiration time of your tokens to something low - about 1 or 2 hours.
- Create a good token refreshing mechanism for the clients
- Add a new `latest_activity` - or whatever you want - date time column/field to your user - or whatever you call it - table/collection
- On every successful request from a client - user is authorized, update this column for the user's row and set it to current date and time - create a utility function for this.
- When analysing, you can safely assume that if you haven't received any request from a user within 1/2 hours - hence the short lifetime for your token above, the user is logged out.

You could even do this in a different database altogether, something like SQLite. Much faster.